# sprintf doesn't seem to grab zeroth string

Tags: printf

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
char list[3][7] = { "One", "Two", "Three"} ;
char item[7];    // originally I had posted "char item[3];" by mistake
int i;

for( i=0; i<2; i++ ) {
    sprintf(item, "%-7s",  list[i]);
    printf( "%d %s", i, item );
}
printf("\n\r");
for( i=0; i<2; i++ ) {
    sprintf(item, "%-7s",  list[i]);
    printf( "%d %s", i, item );
}
printf("\n\r");

return 0;
}
```

I expect the following output

```
0 One    1 Two    
0 One    1 Two
```

However, instead I get:

```
0 One    1 Two    
0        1 Two
```

Note the missing text "One" the second time it prints.

Can someone explain what's happening here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `item` declared as:

```
char item[7];
```

the code exposes undefined behaviour because `sprintf(item, "%-7s")` attempts to write **at least** 8 characters into `item`.

The [documentation of `sprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) explains (the emphasis is mine):

> Writes the results to a character string buffer. *The behavior is undefined if the string to be written (plus the terminating null character) exceeds the size of the array pointed to by buffer*.

`-7` in the format string `"%-7s"` is interpreted as:

> *(optional)* integer value or `*` that specifies *minimum field width*. The result is padded with space characters (by default), if required, on the left when right-justified, or on the right if left-justified. In the case when `*` is used, the width is specified by an additional argument of type `int`. If the value of the argument is negative, it results with the `-` flag specified and positive field width. (**Note: This is the minimum width: The value is never truncated.**)

In order to avoid the undefined behaviour, the size of `item` must be at least `8` but keep in mind that if the string to format is longer than `7` characters it is not truncated, the result becomes longer than `8` characters and it overflows `item` again.

---

#### Why you get the output you get?

The calls to `sprintf(item, "%-7s",  list[i]);` in the first loop write 8 characters in a buffer of 7 characters. The extra character (which is `\0`) incidentally happens to overwrite the first character of `list[0]` changing it into an empty string. **This is just one random behaviour, compiling the code with a different compiler or different compiling options could produce a different behaviour**.

Answer (score 1):

When you do the `sprintf(item, "%-7s",  list[i]);` you are, essentially, copying the string from `list[i]` into your char array `item`.
So `list[2]` -> "three" is 5 chars plus the nul terminator, but `item` is only 3 chars long -- you are overflowing `item` and writing over some other memory, which could very well be part of  `list`.

Change item to be `char item[7]` so it matches the length of 7 declared in your 2nd dimension in `list[3][7]`.  When I did that I got your expected output.
(I used https://repl.it/languages/C to test)

Comment: I edited the question - I inadvertently changed the char item[ ] line when I copied.

Comment: The problem still occurs.  After some experimenting it seems that the relationship between the %-7s and the lengths of the items in the char array matters. If the number in the format string is one less than the length of item, it works OK.